# Akka Streams Hikari Connection Pool for MySQL Streaming

Tags: scala, akka-stream, hikaricp, slick-3.0

I am streaming data from mysql using Slick 3 and Akka Streams.

This is how I build my source

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
val enableJdbcStreaming: (java.sql.Statement) => Unit = {statement =>
    if (statement.isWrapperFor(classOf[com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl])) {
       statement.unwrap(classOf[com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl]).enableStreamingResults()
    }
  }
val query = Tables.Foo.filter(r => r.isActive === true)
     .map(r => r.id).result.withStatementParameters(statementInit = enableJdbcStreaming)
Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(query))
```

My application runs for like 20 minutes and then shuts down with the following error

```
[error] Exception in thread "abhipool network timeout executor" java.lang.NullPointerException
[info] 15:31:46 INFO  [HikariPool] - abhipool - Close initiated...
[error]     at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.setSocketTimeout(MysqlaProtocol.java:1397)
[error]     at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession$1.run(MysqlaSession.java:401)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have a feeling that because my query is running for a very long time there is some kind of timeout occurring which is initiating this shutdown.

My connection

```
mysql {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  properties {
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url  = "jdbc:mysql://foo:3306/bar?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=America/Chicago"
    user = "foo"
    password = "bar"
  }
  connectionTimeout = 0
  idleTimeout = 0
  maxLifetime = 0
  maxConnections = 40
  minConnections = 10
  poolName = "abhipool"
  numThreads = 10
}
```

Dependencies

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.1",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.6",
```

How can I configure my application database connections so that even if my streaming application streams data for several days... it keeps running.

There is an extremely lengthy conversation about this same issue [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/236) but it doesn't tell me how to really fix this issue. This issues makes it totally impossible to write long running streaming tasks which use Mysql as a source.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the MySQL driver by adding parameters in the URL

```
url  = "jdbc:mysql://foo:3306/bar?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=America/Chicago&socketTimeout=30000"
```

I put 30000 for the sake of the example, put the right value that fits your need

Comment: what happens after 30000? my job will run for days.

Comment: then change the value so that it's one week, or am I missing something?